# Can a structured (text) document be effectively encrypted

Tags: encryption, decryption, documents

My situation:

I want to encrypt an HTML document. My question is, if the following is known, is that going to weaken encryption?

- It is a text-based document
- It starts with `<DOCTYPE HTML>` or a few variants of
- This is followed by an `<HTML>` tag, followed by a `<HEAD>` tag, which contains a number of '

Would this knowledge help a hacker to decrypt without the decrypt key? Would such knowledge make my documents effectively un-encryptable?

My apologies if this is a very simple question. I am a neophyte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you refer to is a [known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) where part of the original text is known to the attacker. While simple encryption schemes are known to be vulnerable against such attacks [modern ciphers are considered to be safe against this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks). With these modern ciphers all the known-plaintext allows is to verify if the decrypted result matches the original input, but it is still a brute-force attack over all possible encryption keys needed since all possible  keys are equally probable.

In other words: it might be a problem if you run your own encryption. It is not a problem if you **properly** use established modern encryption.